# mod_rewrite on fasthosts

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I've installed Wordpress here http://www.trsmithroofing.co.uk/flat_roof_blog and I've noticed that URL re-writes are working nicely.

Here's an example of one.
    http://trsmithroofing.co.uk/flat_roof_blog/index.php/2010/10/single-garage-flat-roof/

Knowing this works, I'm wondering why I cannot get re-writes to work on the same server... I have a simple rule which I can get working on my local host, but when I try it out 'live' it doesn't work...

Here's the rule I've got

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule retest-choice-(.*)\.htm$ retest.php?choice=$1
```

On a localhost I can navigate to `retest-choice-1.htm` and it will correctly request `retest.php?choice=1` It just won't work on the fasthosts account.

I've been struggling with this for a long time, but now I know Wordpress has managed to get it working, I'm asking if anyone can explain how so that I can use the same method. Thanks in advance, you guys on Stack overflow have yet to fail me.

Shane

Comment: Define "won't work". What happens exactly? Does a server error come up?

Comment: I create a simple IF statement in a PHP script to check if the GET variable was being sent. On my localhost it sends ok, on fasthosts it doesn't. :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> h++p://trsmithroofing.co.uk/flat_roof_blog/**index.php**/2010/10/single-garage-flat-roof/

This is not a rewrite. IT points you directly to **index.php**. The rest of directory-like structure is available to php in `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable.

Comment: That makes sense :)   So, I guess my overall answer is that rewrites are disabled on my fasthosts accounts. How would I go about enabling it?

Comment: From http headers I can see server runs **Microsoft-IIS/6.0** not Apache, so you can't rewrite urls using `htaccess`

Comment: Thanks very much. This has solved my long-standing issue. :) Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: I've switched to a linux operating system. Hopefully this will make life a little easier :)